# Right 3D coordinate computation in axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I draw a parametric plot using `pgfplots` and I want to add a specific point on the curve. I have used `addplot3` + `coordinates` to add a specific marker on the curve at specific coordinates. This point is well positioned (in red).
Now I want to add a specific text on this point using `\coordinate` on the `axis` environment. I have tried direct coordinates and `axis cs` but none is working. The additional weird thing is that in the pgfplots documentation it is written (version 1.16, section 4.17.1) that `axis cs` is the default coordinate system in `axis` environment and can be omitted. However, if I remove `axis cs` the point is not the same.
I am sure, I am missing something :-).

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

%parameters
\pgfmathsetmacro{\vrotP}{pi/4}
\def\lengthb{4}
\def\lengthh{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\timeTot}{4*pi/\vrotP}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\timeMid}{\timeTot/2}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\timeRef}{7}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function={%
    theta(\t)=\vrotP*\t;
    px(\t)=\lengthb*cos(theta(\t));
    py(\t)=\lengthb*sin(theta(\t));
    pz(\t)=-\lengthh*theta(\t);
    }%
]
\begin{axis}[axis lines=center,
    axis on top,
    samples y=0,
    trig format plots=rad,
    xmax=5,
    xmin=-5,
    ymax=5,
    ymin=-5,
    zmin=-45,
    zmax=0,
    ]
    % \addplot[variable=t,domain=0:10,samples=50]{pz(t)};
    \addplot3[blue,line width=2pt,variable=t,domain=0:\timeTot,samples=100]({px(t)},{py(t)},{pz(t)});
    % point M
    \addplot3+[red,only marks,line width=2pt] coordinates{({px(\timeRef)},{py(\timeRef)},{pz(\timeRef)})};
    %
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpX}{px(\timeRef)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpY}{py(\timeRef)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tmpZ}{pz(\timeRef)}
    \coordinate (orig) at (axis cs:0,0,0);
    \coordinate (M) at (axis cs:\tmpX,\tmpY,\tmpZ);
    \coordinate (Mp) at (\tmpX,\tmpY,\tmpZ);
    \draw(orig)--(M);
    \draw(orig)--(Mp);
    \node[anchor=south] at (orig) {$O$};
    \node[] at (M) {$M$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image: result]

Comment: Regarding what the manual said, you didn't read the footnote: "As of pgfplots version 1.11 and compat=1.11. All older versions explicitly require the prefix; coordinates without the prefix will be placed at the wrong position." So you need `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` or some higher version.

Comment: Try `\addplot3+[red,only marks,line width=2pt] coordinates{({px(\timeRef)},{py(\timeRef)},{pz(\timeRef)})}
    node[label=above:{$A$}] {};`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Thank you for your comment that confirms that I missed something :-)

Comment: @ferahfeza Thank you for your proposition that works well.